# How to convert CImage to Base64 string in MFC C++

Tags: c++, image, mfc, base64

I'm porting some code from C# to C++ with MFC and one thing have stopped me. The original code generated an image and then encoded it as a base64 string to use for en embedded image when generating an HTML file.

The original code first converts it to a byte array

```
private byte[] AsBytes(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
      using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
      {
           image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
           return ms.ToArray();
      }
}
```

The conversion to Base64 is then a simple call, `Convert.ToBase64String(pictureAsBytes)` for MFC there is `Base64Encode` while not as nice it appears to do the job. The problem is going from CImage to CByteArray (or something else useful).

The code I have causes a lot of headache, but it looks like

```
AsBytes(CImage &image, CByteArray &bytes)
{
    int pitch = image.GetPitch();
    int size = abs(pitch) * image.GetHeight();
    const BYTE *src = (BYTE *)image.GetBits();

    if(pitch < 0)
    {
        src -= size;
    }
    
    BYTE *pBitmapData = new BYTE[size];
    memcpy(pBitmapData, src, size * sizeof(BYTE));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        bytes.Add(pBitmapData[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`CImage::Save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class#save) has an overload that takes an `IStream` interface. That allows you to serialize the image data to memory.

Answer (score 0):

After some fixes my AsBytes became

```
bool AsBytes(CImage &image, CByteArray &bytes)
{
    IStream *pStream = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, TRUE, &pStream);

    if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        hr = image.Save(pStream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatPNG);
        if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
        {
            // Get size
            ULARGE_INTEGER liSize;
            IStream_Size(pStream, &liSize);
            // Assume no huge files
            int size = liSize.QuadPart;
            BYTE *result = new BYTE[size];

            // Set to start
            LARGE_INTEGER offset;
            offset.HighPart = 0;
            offset.LowPart = 0;
            offset.QuadPart = 0;
            hr = pStream->Seek(offset, STREAM_SEEK_SET, 0);

            ULONG read;
            hr = pStream->Read(result, size, &read);
            if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
            {
                bytes.SetSize(read * sizeof(BYTE));
                memcpy(bytes.GetData(), result, read * sizeof(BYTE));
            }

            delete [] result;
            pStream->Release();

            return true;
        }
    }
    pStream->Release();
    return false;
}
```

It now uses stream to convert it.

Comment: This truncates the image. It assumes the entire data size were the size of its pixel data only. This isn't correct, as any of the supported image file formats contains metadata whose size is greater than zero. You can verify this by saving `bytes` to a file, and then trying to open it in an image viewer.

Comment: Also, `new BYTE[size]` is never cleaned up.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. I've fixed it and it work for generated images, but if I try it on an image loaded from disk it throws an exception.

Comment: It's hard to tell why (or even where) things go wrong. This implementation is ultimately the same as mine (just with a second ephemeral allocation). I tried mine with different files loaded from disk (PNG, JPG, GIF) and didn't run into any issues. What exceptions are you seeing (C++ or SEH), and where do they originate?

Comment: @IInspectable It's very strange I get a "Access violation reading location" for loaded image, but not for generated. I'll try to create a test program.

Answer (score 0):

To serialize a [`CImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class) object into a stream of bytes you can use its [`CImage::Save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class#save) overload that accepts an [`IStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream) interface, and pass it a memory stream. Since we don't know the resulting size ahead of time we have to make do with a stream that grows as required. [`SHCreateMemStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream) can be constructed with defaults for that purpose.

The following implementation serializes a `CImage` encoded as PNG data into a `std::vector<uint8_t>`:

```cpp
#include <atlimage.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<uint8_t> as_bytes(CImage const& img)
{
    // Serialize image to memory stream
    CComPtr<IStream> stream {};
    stream.Attach(::SHCreateMemStream(nullptr, 0));
    _com_util::CheckError(img.Save(stream, Gdiplus::ImageFormatPNG));

    // Find size in bytes
    ULARGE_INTEGER size {};
    _com_util::CheckError(stream->Seek({}, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, &size));
    if (size.HighPart != 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Images larger than 4GiB not supported");
    }

    // Read memory stream into vector
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes(size.QuadPart);

    _com_util::CheckError(stream->Seek({}, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr));
    ULONG bytes_read { 0 };
    _com_util::CheckError(stream->Read(bytes.data(),
                                       static_cast<ULONG>(bytes.size()),
                                       &bytes_read));

    return bytes;
}
```

The code is using C++ exceptions to report errors, making the function more natural to use. The implementation leaves some room for improvement, in particular the additional allocation of `bytes` plus the copy. A possible alternative would be to implement the `IStream` interface with a class that internally writes to a `vector` directly. This would allow for an implementation without copying data around.

For completeness, here's a base64-encoder that doesn't rely on ATL's implementation. It's using [`CryptBinaryToStringA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa) instead:

```cpp
#include <wincrypt.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32.lib")

std::string to_base64(std::vector<uint8_t> const& bytes)
{
    // Return empty string on empty input
    if (bytes.empty())
    {
        return {};
    }

    // Change as desired
    auto const flags { CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 | CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF };

    // Request required character count (including NUL character)
    DWORD chars_required {};
    if (!::CryptBinaryToStringA(bytes.data(), static_cast<DWORD>(bytes.size()), flags,
                                nullptr, &chars_required)
        || chars_required < 1)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error { "CryptBinaryToStringA() failed" };
    }

    // Create a sufficiently sized string and have the API write into it
    std::string base64(chars_required - 1, 0);
    if (!::CryptBinaryToStringA(bytes.data(), static_cast<DWORD>(bytes.size()), flags,
                                base64.data(), &chars_required))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error { "CryptBinaryToStringA() failed" };
    }

    return base64;
}
```

This requires C++17 to compile for the `std::string::data()` call to return a non-`const` pointer. Note that overwriting the trailing NUL terminator in the `std::string` with another NUL terminator is also well defined as of C++<something>.

And with that you have a nice command line utility that base64-encodes images:

```cpp
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t const* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    std::wstring const src { argv[1] };
    CImage src_img {};
    _com_util::CheckError(src_img.Load(src.c_str()));

    auto const bytes = as_bytes(src_img);
    auto const base64 = to_base64(bytes);

    printf("%s", base64.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```